# SQL - Convert seconds to hh:mm:ss

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I convert a duration in seconds into formatted `hh:mm:ss` in SQL?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: could someone please explain the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

SQL's `sec_to_time()`.

Example:

`select sec_to_time(10000)` yields `02:46:40`

Comment: Did you just ask a question and then immediately answer it...?

Comment: yes i did! couldn't find the solution on stackoverflow and figured i should add a solution i found.